# How to detect if scrollToItem will scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to scroll a cell at a specific location (`.bottom`) and after the scroll animation finishes run some code. The problem is that `scrollToItem` function does not provide a completion handler therefor the only solution is to use the delegate (`scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation`). Using that I have one problem though, if the cell is already at that location `.didEndScrollAnim`. will never be called.

Is there a way to find if a cell is already at `UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.bottom` ?

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: [.bottom,.centeredHorizontally], animated: true)
```

I want to be able to run a part of code when the cell is at the desired location [`.bottom`] and also animate the scroll if a scroll is needed.

Comment: Easiest way to do this implement `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`  called when scroll view grinds to a halt

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` func and this func will call when scroll view grinds (comes) to a halt.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let secondItemIndex = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0)
    categoryCollectionView.selectItem(at: secondItemIndex, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)

}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let secondItemIndex = IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0)
    categoryCollectionView.selectItem(at: secondItemIndex, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)

}
```

// Scroll way doesn't effect this func so you can specify any position as you want

Comment: This function is not called when the view is scrolled or when the animation ends.`collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: [.bottom, .centeredHorizontally])` will scroll to that item with out calling the function if there is no halt in that index path.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIScrollViewDelegate.scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(UIScrollView)` to be notified when an invocation of `UICollectionView.scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)` has finished its animation.

`UIScrollViewDelegate.scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` isn't called when scrolling is initiated programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a way, but it involves calling `scrollViewDidScroll` repeatedly, which does reduce the performance of the screen.

In the func `scrollViewDidScroll`:

```
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)) {
        //reach bottom, here your code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the `animated` param to `false` and use `UIView.animate()` to detect the animation completion.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
        // do something after scroll animation completed
    }
)
```